# How to use "RowNumber()" in a query using PortCMIS?

Tags: c#, .net, cmis, dotcmis

I'm working in a project using the Apache Chemistry PortCMIS. The project is alredy developed, but i'm gonna make a new improvement and a don't experience with that.
I need to list documents from a specificy range of lines, to paging. 
It's like de RowNumber() in SQL, like this: SELECT * FROM table WHERE rownum > 10 and rownum <= 20. 
Sorry for my bad english.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Paging and skipping is explained here: https://chemistry.apache.org/docs/cmis-samples/samples/lists/index.html#paging-and-skipping